# Kill Java Proccess And Restart Again

Tags: java, linux, linux-kernel, operating-system, pid

[image: java killing and ProcessId]

I recently switch on my system and without starting any application on port 8080.No applications are running, but the system automatically runs by default if I'm killing the PID of 8080 another PID will assign to automatically.Even there is no Java application running

Comment: And what is the question?

Comment: why the java process 8080 it is again start by itself even after killing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you have a tomcat server that starts automatically, try to deactivate its daemon with `sudo service tomcat stop`

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one to kill the process.

```
try {
        moveTaskToBack(true);
        android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
        System.exit(1);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Crashlytics.logException(e); //If You have installed Firebase Crashlytics
    }
```